Proof: Let $\epsilon>0$ and $x'\in\mathbb{R}^L_+$ be such that $\|x'-x\|\geq\epsilon$. Then $\alpha(x')$ belongs to some $[\alpha_0,\alpha_1]$
See Proposition 3.C.1 from MWG
Continue from this post, the book (MWG) then started the proof that $\alpha(x)$ is a continuous function:

We now argue that $\alpha(x)$ is a continuous function at all $x$; that is, for any sequence $\{x^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha(x^n)=\alpha(x)$. Hence, consider a sequence $\{x^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$.

Quick question here: The reason that this paragraph is true is based on the fact that every point of $\mathbb{R}^L_+$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{R}^L_+$, am I right? Because otherwise the sequential characterization of continuity will not be sufficient to prove $\alpha(x)$ is continuous at every $x\in\mathbb{R}^L_+$.
Then the book put:

We note that the sequence $\{\alpha(x^n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ must have a convergent subsequence. By monotonicity, for any $\epsilon>0$, $\alpha(x')$ lies in a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}_+$, $[\alpha_0,\alpha_1]$, for all $x'$ such that $\|x'-x\|\leq\epsilon$ (see the figure below). Since $\{x^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $x$, there exists an $N$ such that $\alpha(x^n)$ lies in this compact set for all $n>N$. But any infinite sequence that lies in a compact set must have a convergent subsequence.


My question about the bolded part in this paragraph: Intuitively, this makes sense to me, but I had a difficult time proving this rigorously. I rephrased the bolded part as follows:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $x'\in\mathbb{R}^L_+$ be such that $\|x'-x\|\leq\epsilon$. Then there are $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\alpha(x')\in[\alpha_0,\alpha_1]$.

Here is my attempt to prove it:

Assume to the contrary that there does not exist $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\alpha(x')\in[\alpha_0,\alpha_1]$. Then this means either $\alpha(x')$ is negative or $\alpha(x')=+\infty$. If $\alpha(x')<0$, then $0\gg\alpha(x')e$, and monotonicity would imply $0\sim0\succ\alpha(x')e\sim x'$, contradicts the fact that $x\succsim0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^L_+$. Now suppose $\alpha(x')=+\infty$. Denote $x'=(x'_1,\dots,x'_L) \in \mathbb{R}^L_+$ and let $x''=(x'_1+1,\dots,x'_L+1)$. Then $x''\gg x'$ and so $x''\succ x'$. However, $\alpha(x'')\leq\alpha(x')=+\infty$, which contradicts the fact that $\alpha(\cdot)$ represents $\succsim$. Therefore, the above statement holds.

Is my attempt correct?
Thanks a lot for any help!

We don't need $X$ (domain of the utility) to be equal to the set of its limit points to use the sequential characterisation of continuity. In other words, the sequential characterisation of continuity also holds when $X$ is not equal to the set of its limit points.
Given $x\in\mathbb{R}^L_+$, to get $\alpha_0,\alpha_1$,
consider
$\alpha_0=0$ and
$\alpha_1=\max_{1\leq i \leq L} x_i+\epsilon$
Check that for any $x'\in\mathbb{R}^L_+$ such that $||x'-x||\leq\epsilon$, $\alpha(x')\in [\alpha_0,\alpha_1]$.

Indeed, $X$ need not be closed or equal to the set of its limit points. But every point of $X$ have to be a limit point of $X$, in order for the sequential characterization of continuity to hold for all $x\in X$. In other words, let $E$ be the set of limit points of $X$, we need $X\subseteq E$.

I don't think this condition is required. Please provide the definition of limit point of the set you are using. I'll try and provide a proof of characterisation.

Consider, for example, $X=[0,2]\bigcup{4}\bigcup(8,10]$ and the function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$.  Then $f$ is always continuous at $x=4$ (according to the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity). However, the sequential characterization of continuity does not hold at $x=4$ because it is not a limit point.

Sequential characterisation holds because any sequence $(x_n)$ that converges to 4 consists of constant 4 in all but finitely many terms of the sequence. Consequently, $\lim f(x_n)=  \lim f(4) = f(4)$ for all such sequences.

Not exactly. By definition (see Baby Rudin), a point $p$ is a limit point of the set $E$ if every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $q\neq p$ such that $q\in E$. As a result, "a finite point set has no limit points". Moreover, the sequential characterization of continuity says that a function $f$ is continuous at a limit point $p$ if and only if $\lim_{x\top}f(x)=f(p)$.

@Champa It is not true that  the sequential charaterization says necessarily that the point must be a limit point. Some texts may say that because they consider obviuous what Amit said in the comment above, that at an isolated point the condition is obvious, and they focus on the more interesting case of a limit point.

@BakerStreet I see. Yes, that does makes sense. Thanks a lot!

@Amit Thank you very much! Now I get your point.

@Champa You are welcome. You are right that this matter in some text can be confusing, but many text don't make this confusion. The point is exactly what Amit said.

@Amit May I ask how would you prove $\alpha(x')\leq\alpha_1$, where $\alpha_1=\max{x_1,\dots,x_L}+\epsilon$. I wanted to prove it by contradiction, and I think the contradiction should be that if $\alpha(x')>\alpha_1$ then $|x'-x|$ would be bigger than $\epsilon$. But I couldn't formalize a proof. Can you please help me with it?

@Amit Does this work: Assume to the contrary that $\alpha(x')>\alpha_1$. Let $x''=(x_1+\epsilon,\dots,x_L+\epsilon)$. Then $\alpha(x')e\gg x''$ and the monotonicity implies $x'\sim\alpha(x')e\succ x''$. However, $x_i''=x_i+\epsilon\geq x_i'$, because otherwise $|x'-x|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^L(x_i'-x_i)^2}>\epsilon$. Thus $x''\geq x'$ and the lemma in this post (https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/58383/question-about-the-step-proving-alphax-represents-preferences-in-the-proof) implies $x''\succsim x'$. We have a contradiction.

Consider any $x'\in\mathbb{R}^L_+$ such that $||x'-x||\leq \epsilon$. This implies that $|x_i'-x_i|\leq \epsilon$ for all $i\in{1,2,\ldots,L}$. This further implies that $x_i'\leq x_i+\epsilon\leq \alpha_1$ for all $i\in{1,2,\ldots,L}$. Therefore, by monotonicity, $\alpha(x')\leq \alpha_1$.
